# SMB Client for NodeJS AWS Lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, samba, smb

I'm trying to find a package or figure out a way to use a SMB client or Samba client to put files on an FSx share. I found this example: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/enabling-smb-access-for-serverless-workloads/. Problem is I am writing in nodejs not python. Anyone know a nodjs package or a way to install SMBClient with a custom resource for the cloud formation template?

Answer (score 0):

I having the same problem, ended up creating a custom docker image for my code and install samba-client as dependency.

here is my Dockerfile -

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:18
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y samba-client

WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY src ./src

CMD [ "/var/task/src/index.handler" ]
```

And for NodeJS I used [samba-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/samba-client) -

```
const SambaClient = require('samba-client');

const client = new SambaClient({
  "share": `\\shared-path`,
  "domain": `WORKGROUP`,
  "username": "",
  "password": ""
});

await client.getFile('someRemotePath/file', 'destinationFolder/name');
```

Comment: I was wondering about that. I was guessing that there must be a way to configure the container to install the Samba client but I wasn't sure how to do that. Now I just have to figure out how to customize the lambda container.